# Capturing and streaming with ffmpeg while displaying locally

Tags: ffmpeg

I can capture with ffmpeg from a device, I can transcode the audio/video, I can stream it to ffserver.

How can I capture and stream with ffmpeg while showing locally what is captured?

Up to now I've been using VLC to capture and stream to localhost, then ffmpeg to get that stream, transcode it again, and stream to ffserver.

I'd like to do this using ffmpeg only.

Thank you.

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs

Comment: That clarifies how to create a second output, but I don't want to transcode to 2 outputs (like 2 files or 2 streaming servers), I want one of them to be local display.

Comment: You copy the source to the local output

Answer (score 3):

**Option A**: Use `ffmpeg` with multiple outputs and a separate player:

- output 1: copy source without transcoding and pipe it or send it to a local port
- output 2: transcode and send to server

  Example using `ffplay`

  ```
  ffmpeg -f x11grab [grab parameters] -i :0.0 \
  [transcode parameters] -f [transcode output] \
  -f rawvideo - | ffplay -f rawvideo [grab parameters] -i -
  ```

**Option B**: `ffmpeg`only with OpenGL and a SDL window (requires SDL and  `--enable-opengl`)

```
    ffmpeg -f x11grab [grab parameters] -i :0.0 \
    [transcode parameters] -f [transcode output] \
    -f opengl "Window title"
```

Comment: Does the pipe "|" really work like that for windows cmd line?

Comment: It should as it's stdout to stdin. I don't do Windows though so you have to try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `tee` separately what is more error prone for me (I couldn't get [aergistal's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40703054/3383640) to work):

```
cat file | tee >(program_1) [...] >(program_n) | destination
```

In this case:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://url -codec:a aac -b:a 192k -codec:v copy -f mpegts - | \
       tee >(ffplay -f mpegts -i -) | \
       ffmpeg -y -f mpegts -i - -c copy /path/to/file.mp4
```

(Tested with `ffmpeg v:3.2.11` [current in Debian stable])

Comment: while this works out of the box on Linux, how about windows ffmpeg?

Comment: @andrixnet I don't use Windows and thus can't say anything about it.