# How can I get the graphical output from another program?

Tags: python, flask, remote-desktop

I'm trying to build my own remote desktop which can be accessed by the browser. My first idea was building a server (with python I would use flask) and including the graphical output of the OS into my html page. Because I thought that that would be difficult/not possible my next plan is to get just the graphical output of one program which I started from the server.

Please tell me how I could do this or how I could start with this project.

Comment: there are various protocol to access remote desktop, first try researching that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a daunting task, but I guess this procedure would be a good start for a prototype.

1. Capture the display using ffmpeg:
   [Capturing and streaming with ffmpeg while displaying locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40689505/capturing-and-streaming-with-ffmpeg-while-displaying-locally)
2. Create a route to view this stream: [Streaming MOVIE Python flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53145242/streaming-movie-python-flask)
3. Listen to click/keyboard events on the page and relay them back to source, apply these interactions using a input driver